# how to read strings using c#

Tags: c#, string

how can i read string values

**QuoteNo:32586/CustomerNo:ABCDEF/TotalAmount:32/Processed:No**

i want to read the values of the strings in any order

Comment: so your output like:
QuoteNo:/CustomerNo:ABCDEF/TotalAmount:/Processed:No

Comment: Read strings from what?  For what?

Comment: StackOverflow Jeopardy. Guess the question for $400, Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking to do, but from your given string it may be the following

```
string input = "QuoteNo:32586/CustomerNo:ABCDEF/TotalAmount:32/Processed:No";

var query = from pair in input.Split('/')
            let items = pair.Split(':')
            select new
            {
                Part = items[0],
                Value = items[1]
            };

 // turn into list and access by index 
var list = query.ToList();

// or turn into dictionary and access by key
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary 
    = query.ToDictionary(item => item.Part, item => item.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. split the string by / into array
2. loop through the array and split each entry by : (basically creating key pair value), shove that into a dictionary, the key will be the array at index 0 and value at index 1
3. Once you have your dictionary, you can just do something like: myData["QuoteNo"] or myData["CustomerNo"]

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for neebie questions but i assume a certain level of google-ability

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread60361.html

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/12793-c%23-reading-each-character-of-a-string/

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6030362.html

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "QuoteNo:32586/CustomerNo:ABCDEF/TotalAmount:32/Processed:No";
string split = str.Split('/');
foreach(string s in split)
{
   int index = s.IndexOf(':');
   if (index <= 0 || index + 1 >= str.Length) throw new Exception();
   string name = s.SubString(0,index);
   string value = s.SubString(index+1);
}
```